# django: get model instance with dynamic variable name and value

Tags: python, model, get, instance

I have the following error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'attrName1' into field. Choices are: codesectrepmodel, configCons, id`. My code:

```
modelName1="ConfigConsModel"
model1 = get_model('actsInformationRetrieval', modelName1)
print "model attr", model1._meta.get_all_field_names() #displays ['codesectrepmodel', 'configCons', 'id']
print "attrName1", attrName1 #displays configCons
print "attr1", attr1 #displays ECOFIN
attr1Instance=model1.objects.get(attrName1=attr1)
```

What's wrong?
I think the problem is that `get_model` returns the model class, not an object. Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are doing

```
.get(attrName1=attr1)
```

the `attrName1` is actually keyword argument but not the variable. If you want to name fields dynamically you can try

```
.get(**{attrName1: attr1})
```

Comment: well, I meant to replace `attr1Instance=model1.objects.get(attrName1=attr1)` with `attr1Instance=model1.objects.get(**{attrName1: attr1})`

Comment: well, this is just a standard syntax for passing keyword arguments as a dictionary in python http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments